# R: Keeping numbers of loops flexible (by addressing dimensions without indexing)

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, grid, minimize

Hello little and big helpers,

I have a problem in R concerning a dataset with variable number of dimensons, causing a changing number of for-loops. I will provide an example that is somewhat similar to my problem (albeit of course different topic).

Imagine we have the following data set: in our R-wonderland there are 5 states. In each state there are 6 towns. In each town there are 10 burger restaurants. We know the burger price for each of the 10*6*5 = 300 restaurants. Now I'd like to know the cheapest burger for every town in every state.

```
x <- rnorm(300,5,1) # create random "burger prices" with mean=5$ and std.dv 1$ for all 300 restaurants
x_Array <- array(x,dim=c(10,6,5)) # get the prices in order: 1st dim = 10 restaurants per town, 2nd dim = 6 towns in state, 3rd dim = 5 states

x_Subset <- array(0,dim=c(dim(x_Array)[2],dim(x_Array)[3])) # prepare a subset which will contain "location" of the cheapest burger in town & state

# find cheapest burger for each town in each state -> this I want to keep flexible in terms of number of dimensions/loops
for (i in 1:dim(x_Array)[2]){
  for (j in 1:dim(x_Array)[3]){
    x_Subset[i,j] <- which(x_Array == min(x_Array[,i,j]))
  }
}
```

By eliminating the variation of restaurants we reduce the original data set by one dimension (10 restaurants -> cheapest ONE restaurant).

The problem is that in my case the dimesions are not fixed. Imagine I'd like to add different nations to my data set, so there might be 10 restaurants in 6 towns and 5 states of 4 nations on 3 continents - this 5D problem would result in an x_Subset containing 4 dimensions. I'd have to set up a loop of depth four.

How do I keep those numbers of loops flexible? I had a similar problem which I was able to solve using

```
Expand.grid()
```

But that does not reduce the dimension by one. There would be a new item for restaurant 1,2,3,... for each town, state (,nation, continent, ...). However I only need the cheapest restaurant (> min()) on the first dim and all combinations for the rest of the dataset.

I think it would be possible if I could only solve this synthax issue:

```
x_Subset_vector <- x_Subset[,1] # how do I write this without knowing the n° of dimensions of x_Subset? Like: "get all values of the first item (in this case: "column") in the second dimension"
```

Or for the burger example:

```
x_Subset_vector <- x_Subset[,1,1] # 3D problem ([restaurants, towns, states])
x_Subset_vector <- x_Subset[,1,1,1,1] # 5D problem ([..., nation,continent])
```

In easy words: how do I automize the numbers of "commas" in the index of x_Subset?

Sorry for making you hungry. You deserve hell of a great burger for helping me with this one!

Thank you so much, guys!

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer to use multidimensional array over `data.frame`?

Comment: The items are all numeric, so I figured out that arrays are the easiest to implement. I have to admit that I am not used to working with data.frames and don't know their advantages apart from containing different data formats next to each other.